# Reaction between HCl and NaHCO3

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, separation-techniques

I want to know why in the reaction between HCl and NaHCO3, we have CO2 and H2O instead of H2CO3 ?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid#Chemical_equilibrium

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3 is stable at high pressure or excess of water only